# Plugin with Fatal error

Tags: plugins

This throws a fatal error at line 242. How can I fix it? (Wordpress 6. PHP 8.1)

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "WikiLinksPlugin" in /home/wp_tuxz2-40o/example.com/wp-content/plugins/wiki-page-links/wikipagelinks.php:242 Stack trace: #0 /home/wp_tuxz2-40o/example.com/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2314): include_once() #1 /home/wp_tuxz2-40o/example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php(192): plugin_sandbox_scrape('wiki-page-links...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/wp_tuxz2-40o/example.com/wp-content/plugins/wiki-page-links/wikipagelinks.php on line 242

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Wiki Page Links
Plugin URI: http://www.flyingsquirrel.ca/
Description: Automatically links to pages, wiki-style.
Author: Darcy Casselman
Version: 0.4
Author URI: http://www.flyingsquirrel.ca/

    Darcy Casselman

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


*/

require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/post.php";

if ( !class_exists("WikiLinksPlugin") ) {
class WikiLinksPlugin {

    var $name = "WikiPageLinksPlugin";
    var $shortName = "WikiPageLinks";
    var $longName = "Wiki Page Links Plugin";
    var $adminOptionsName = "WikiPageLinksPluginAdminOptions";
    
    var $debug = false;

    var $defaultShortcuts = array(
        'wiki' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s',
    );
    
    function log($message) {
        if ($this->debug)
            error_log($message . "\n", 3, "/tmp/wikilinks.log");
    
    }
    
    //PHP4 constructor
    function WikiLinksPlugin() {$this->__construct();} 
    
    //PHP5 constructor
    function __construct() {
        // WordPress Hooks
        //add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'addAdminPanel'));  
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'wiki_filter'));
    }
    
    function _install() {
        $this->log("Wiki Links installed!");
    }
    
    function _uninstall() {
        $this->log("Wiki Links uninstalled!");
    }
    
    /**
     * Added by Daniel Llewellyn (Fremen):
     * separate out the viewed title from the link name from wikilinks of the form [[link|some user title]]
     */
    function wiki_get_piped_title($link) {
        list($link, $title) = explode('\|', $link, 2);
        if (!$title) $title = $link;
        return array($link, $title);
    }

    /* The filter.
     * Replaces double brackets with links to pages.
     */
    function wiki_filter($content) {
        $options = $this->getAdminOptions();

        //Match only phrases in double brackets.  A backslash can be
        //used to escape the sequence, if you want literal double brackets.
        preg_match_all('/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/', $content, $matches);

        //$matches[1] is an array of all the phrases in double brackets.
        //Dumping all the matches into a hash ensures we only look up
        //each matching page name once.
        $links = array();
        foreach( $matches[1] as $keyword ) {
            $links[$keyword] = current($matches[0]);
            next($matches[0]);
        }

        foreach( $links as $full_link => $match ) {
            // If the "page title" contains a ':', it *may* be a shortcut
            // link rather than a page.  Deal with those first.
            list($prefix, $sublink) = explode(':', $full_link, 2);

            if ( $sublink ) {
                if ( array_key_exists($prefix, $options['shortcuts']) ) {
                    list($link, $subtitle) = $this->wiki_get_piped_title($sublink);
                    $shortcutLink = sprintf( $options['shortcuts'][$prefix],
                        rawurlencode($link));
                    $content = str_replace($match, 
                        "<a href='$shortcutLink'>$subtitle</a>",
                        $content);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
            list($link, $page_title) = $this->wiki_get_piped_title($full_link);

            //We have a page link. 
            //TODO: cut down on db hits and get the list of pages instead.
            if ( $page = get_page_by_title(html_entity_decode($link, ENT_QUOTES)) ) {
                $content = str_replace($match, 
                    "<a href='". get_permalink($page->ID) ."'>$page_title</a>",
                    $content);
            } else if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                //Add a link to create the page if it doesn't exist.
                //TODO: limit showing the link to users who can create posts.

                $home = get_option('siteurl');
                $encodedlink = urlencode($link);
                $content = str_replace($match, "{$page_title}[<a href='$home/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&post_title=$encodedlink' class='nonexistant_page' title='Create this page (requires a valid \"contributer\" account)'>?</a>]", $content);

            } else {
                
                $content = str_replace($match, $page_title, $content);
            }
        }
        
        return $content;
    }

    function getAdminOptions() {
        //defaults
        $options = array(
            'shortcuts' => $this->defaultShortcuts,
        );
    
        $savedOptions = get_option($this->adminOptionsName);
        
        if (!empty($savedOptions)) {
            foreach ($savedOptions as $key => $value) {
                $options[$key] = $value;
            }
        } 
        
        return $options;
    
    }
    
    function saveAdminOptions($options) {
        if (get_option($this->adminOptionsName)) {
            $this->log("Updating option: " . $this->adminOptionsName);
            update_option($this->adminOptionsName, $options);
        } else {
            $this->log("Adding new option: " . $this->adminOptionsName);
            add_option($this->adminOptionsName, $options);
        }
    }
        
    function adminPanel() {  
        $adminOptions = $this->getAdminOptions();
        $submitButton = "submit_Save${shortname}Options";

        if (isset($_POST[$submitButton])) {
            for ( $i=0; $i < $this->shortcutCount; $i++ ) {
                if (isset($_POST["shortcut$i"])) {
                    $adminOptions['feeds'][$i] = $_POST["feeds$i"];
                }
            }
            
            print_r($adminOptions);
            $this->saveAdminOptions($adminOptions);
            
            ?>
            
        <div class="updated"><p><strong>
        <?php  _e("Settings Updated", $this->name); ?>
        </strong></p></div>
        
            <?php
        }
        
        ?>  
        <div class="wrap">  
            <h2><?php echo $longName; ?></h2>  
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
            
            <table class="form-table">
            <tr valign="top">
            
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>

            <input type="text" 
                   name="feeds<?php echo $i; ?>" 
                   value="<?php echo $feed; ?>"
                   size="50" />
            <br />
            
            </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options"
             value="new_option_name,some_other_option,option_etc" />

            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" 
                name="<?php echo $submitButton; ?>" 
                value="<?php _e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
            </p>

            
            </form>
        </div>  
        <?php  
    }    
    
    function addAdminPanel()   
    {  
        add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 
        $this->longName, 
        $this->shortName, 
        10, __FILE__, 
        array(&$this, 'adminPanel'));
    }    

}
}


if (class_exists(WikiLinksPlugin) && !isset($wikiLinks_plugin)) {
    $wikiLinks_plugin = new WikiLinksPlugin();    
}

?>
```

Comment: The `class_exists` value should be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `class_exists(WikiLinksPlugin)` call is calling WikiLinksPlugin as a constant, rather than as a value passed to `class_exists()`.

It should be this (quotes around the class name):

```
if (class_exists( "WikiLinksPlugin" ) && !isset($wikiLinks_plugin)) {
    $wikiLinks_plugin = new WikiLinksPlugin();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does the trick if (class_exists( "WikiLinksPlugin" ) && !isset($wikiLinks_plugin)) { $wikiLinks_plugin = new WikiLinksPlugin(); } Is there a way to write that to the database?